# Browser refresh causing duplicate submission

Tags: javascript, servlets, web

I have a webpage where I can fill some details and submit the form. After submitting the form a result page will be displayed with order number. If I refresh on the result page the form is getting submitted again and new order number is inserted into the database and the new order number is shown in the result page.

What is the best way to solve this issue? Is there any way that I can restrict the submission from the javascript?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I prefer redirecting on the client side after form submission ([Redirect after post](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365146/Redirect-After-Post)).
Find further solution about the subject [here](http://technoesis.net/prevent-double-form-submission/).
In javascript, you can simply call:

```
window.location.replace("ResultsPage");
```